# I need different data on different http action in django rest.Can i do it without making too many serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have to return different data on different action in following `ModelViewset`... and for this purpose I am currently using 3 different serializers...`GetSerializer`, `PutPostSerializer` and `DefaultSerializer`

I was thinking if I can do this any better way (without using too many serializers)....

These ModelSerializers differ in `fields` in `Meta` and `SerializerMethodField` for extra data that i need.

```
class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
def get_serializer_class(self):

      if self.action in ['list',]:
            return GetSerializer
      elif self.action in ['update','partial_update',]:
            return PutPostSerializer
      return DefaultSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an example class from DRF docs, which allows you change fields set when serializer initialized:

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
    controls which fields should be displayed.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
        # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields.keys())
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

Usage example:

```
class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True, fields=('fields_to_exclude',)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

[docs reference](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields)

Comment: thanks for the help...but i want to know that can i specify different action such as list,retrive to get different fields_set here?